# Erroneous mysql syntax error when creating user

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using a list of sql statements in a text file to bootstrap mysql before actually starting it, the command is as follows

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --user=mysql --bootstrap --verbose=0 < $tfile && echo "Successfully run $tfile"
```

And the SQL statements, to update the root users password and create a wordpress users in the $tfile are

```
USE mysql;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
CREATE USER "root"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "1234567890abcdef";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO "root"@"%" WITH GRANT OPTION;
UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD("1234567890abcdef") WHERE user="root";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO "root"@"localhost" WITH GRANT OPTION;
UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD(") WHERE user="root" AND host="localhost";
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `wordpress` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
CREATE USER "wordpress"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "1234567890abcdef";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO "wordpress"@"%" WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

However no matter how K tweak this, I come back to the same error

> ERROR: 1064  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1234567890abcdef' at line 1
>   [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: I'm not sure about MySQL, but in SQL, strings are enclosed in single quotes `'`, not double quotes `"`. Have you tried replacing all double quotes with single ones?

Comment: I have tried that, but I used https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/ to syntax check

Comment: changing it to quotes I get `ERROR: 1064  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1234567890abcdef '' at li
ne 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple mode, MySQL treats `"` as a literal quote, but if ANSI_QUOTES is enabled, then it is used as quote symbol for identifiers.

Check the SQL_MODE, for example session value -

```
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```

And change it if needed. More information - [ANSI_QUOTES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes).

---

Try to change this mode before the script -

```
-- SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES';
SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = '';
USE mysql;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
CREATE USER "root"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "1234567890abcdef";
```

Comment: returned `mysql> SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
+--------------------+
| @@SESSION.sql_mode |
+--------------------+
|                    |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: I have added some details in answer.

Comment: I can create the use now! But this happens when I try to read in values from env variables `mysql> select User,Host from mysql.user;
+-------------+---------------------------------+
| User        | Host                            |
+-------------+---------------------------------+
| $MYSQL_USER | %                               |
| root        | 127.0.0.1                       |
| root        | ::1                             |
| root        | localhost                       |
| root        | wordpress-mysql-403298046-915cl |
+-------------+---------------------------------+)`